# order on Poloniex pass, balances did not change

Tags: poloniex

I made 1 request to create a  sell order on polonium platform, it returned success. 
I see 2 orders in order history

```
 ETH/BTC    Sell    Exchange    0.04683003  0.00583652  0.00000041 BTC
 (0.15%)    0.00027291 BTC  2017-12-20 07:11:44
 ETH/BTC    Sell    Exchange    0.04683003  0.05633578  0.00000396 BTC
 (0.15%)    0.00263424 BTC  2017-12-20 07:11:42
```

not sure why but aggregation of amounts is equal to initial amount i sent in my request.
As far as i understand order succeed, but my balances do not show it.
My ETH balance remain the same as BTC balance. I don't have any open orders as well. How can i understand what happened  with the order ?

Answer (score -1):

Answer is I calculated wrong amount, since i used sell and not buy option.